# Docker compose with redis connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:6379

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am hosting the redis inside docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis/redis-stack:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command:
      - redis-stack-server
      - /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

redis.conf:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 -::1
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
...
```

My connection script (I am running it also inside the docker container):

```js
import { createClient } from "redis";
const redisClient = await createClient({url: "redis://default:1234@redis:6379"})
  .on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err))
  .connect();
```

However, I got:

```
 Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:6379
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16)
     at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
   errno: -111,
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '172.18.0.2',
   port: 6379
 }
```

What's wrong with my connection? How can I solve it?